# OpenLayers2 and GeoJSON - possible to create, modify and delete features?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geojson

I wondered if anyone has some OpenLayers GeoJSON code to read, create, modify and delete features (i.e. instead of using WFS-T)?

This is how far I've come - I've no problem changing the pop-up to a HTML form to modify attributes, it's more the linking the create button to a pop-up to enter data and then catch the move feature event, and last a 'delete feature' button

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
  <script src="../lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
  <script defer='defer' type='text/javascript'>
    var lon = 11.967;
    var lat = 57.7;

    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Open Street Map");

    var trees = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
      "Träd",{
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: 'postgis2geojson.php?geotable=trad&geomfield=wkb_geometry&fields=ogc_fid,%20plats,%20tr%C3%A4dnummer,%20art',
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
          internalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
          externalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")})
        }),
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]
    });            

    var toolbar = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
        displayClass: 'olControlEditingToolbar'
    });
    toolbar.addControls([
        // this control is just there to be able to deactivate the drawing
        // tools
        new OpenLayers.Control({
            displayClass: 'olControlNavigation'
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(trees, { 
            displayClass: 'olControlModifyFeature'
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(trees, OpenLayers.Handler.Point, {
            displayClass: 'olControlDrawFeaturePoint'
        })
    ]);

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
      projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
      units: "m",
      displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
      controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Scale(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
        toolbar
      ]
    });

    map.addLayers([osm, trees]);

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

    select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(trees);

    trees.events.on({
      "featureselected": onFeatureSelect,
      "featureunselected": onFeatureUnselect
    });

    map.addControl(select);
    select.activate();

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(
      new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
      map.getProjectionObject()
    ), 10);

    function onPopupClose(evt) {
      select.unselectAll();
    }

    function onFeatureSelect(event) {
      var feature = event.feature;
      var content = "<strong>" + feature.attributes.art 
        + "</strong> (Id: " + feature.attributes.trädnummer + ")";
      popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
        feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
        new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
        content,
        null, true, onPopupClose);
        feature.popup = popup;
        map.addPopup(popup);
    }

    function onFeatureUnselect(event) {
      var feature = event.feature;
      if(feature.popup) {
        map.removePopup(feature.popup);
        feature.popup.destroy();
        delete feature.popup;
      }
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
</code>
```

Comment: like http://maps.peterrobins.co.uk/files/ol6.html?

Comment: So when I ADD a feature with the little pencil, what event can I catch to bring up a pop-up to enter data?

Comment: Seem to be getting there - have changed the DrawFeature control to:         new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(trees, OpenLayers.Handler.Point, {
            displayClass: 'olControlDrawFeaturePoint',
            featureAdded: treesFeatureAdded
        }) and created the function treesFeatureAdded - will update the code later